# SQL Server Pivot Ordering issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

my query  returns a pivot table, the first column (nummnth) contain text values like 01,02,03 for the months Jan, Feb, Mar. The problem is that the ordering is 01 , 03 , 02 Instead of 01,02,03.

How could i fix this ???

the query is:

```
   select [nummnth] ,[mnth],[Business Fixed Score],[Business Fixed 
   Sessions],[Business Mobile Score],[Business Mobile Sessions],[Business 
   Merged Score],[Business Merged Sessions] from (Select [nummnth],
   [Mnth],C.* from (
   SELECT [Service],nummnth,mnth,b.A2 as [User_Score],b.A2_Sessions as 
   [Sessions_Count] FROM [QTDB].[dbo].[QTD_BOX_BUS_MERGED_CP] as [b] where 
   YR=2017 
    and [service] = 'Business Fixed' and Agent='ANAME'
   Union 
   SELECT [Service],nummnth,mnth,b.A2 as [User_Score],b.A2_Sessions as 
   [Sessions_Count] 
   FROM [QTDB].[dbo].[QTD_BOX_BUS_MERGED_CP] as [b] where YR=2017 and 
   [service] = 'Business Mobile' and Agent='ANAME'
   UNION all 
   SELECT 'Business Merged' as [Service] ,nummnth,mnth,b.A2 as 
   [User_Score],b.A2_Sessions as [Sessions_Count]  
   FROM [QTDB].[dbo].[QTD_BOX_BUS_AGENT_MNTH_MERGED] as [b]  where YR=2017 
   and Agent='ANAME')  A 
   Cross Apply (Values (A.[Service]+' Score',
   cast(A.[User_Score] as float)),(A.[Service]+' Sessions',cast(A.
   [Sessions_Count] as float))) C (Item,Value)) R Pivot (
   sum(Value) For [Item] in ([Business Fixed Score],
   [Business Fixed Sessions],
   [Business Mobile Score],[Business Mobile Sessions],
   [Business Merged Score],[Business Merged Sessions])) PV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL-Server **there is no implicit order!!** None, never...

You cannot even say *The problem is that the ordering is 01 , 03 , 02 Instead of 01,02,03.* The next call it might return differently.

**The only way to ensure the order is `ORDER BY` on the outermost query!**

Just add `ORDER BY [nummnth]` as last line and check the result.

Comment: I tried the ORDER BY [nummnth] everywhere in the query except at the end, after the PV. Works perfect now.. I feel so stupid but it was a "programming to extreme" period.

Comment: @AndyL. I'm glad, that you could solve your issue. And never mind, everybody feels stupid from time to time :-D